# Remove back button text in tabbar controller more navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am using tab bar controller to show my views, since i have exceeded 5 tabs, all other view automatically move more navigation controller of tabbarcontroller.

My main goal is to remove back button text in all the views present inside the more navigation controller  . I tried  all possible ways of removing the text . Please help me resolving the the issue .

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)


tabBarController!.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "";
```

Please refer my attached screenshot . This is the page am getting from moreNAvaigation controller . So iw ant hide back button text and for it's child views also

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Source ViewController add below code to `viewWillAppear`

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

From this view controller you need to move to destination view controller as follows :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destinationViewController:UIViewController  = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailView") as! UIViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this same issue and found this answer via Google.  The selected answer didn't work for me, so I did some digging and was able to figure this out. 
 Setting the `backBarButtonItem` property on the navigation item for `moreNavigationController` will not do anything, there is another hidden view controller that you need to use...

If you take a look at `moreNavigationController.viewControllers` in the debugger you will see that there is a view controller already in the array called `UIMoreListController`.  You need to set the `backBarButtonItem` property on the `UIMoreListController` instance for this to work.

This should work (in a UITabBarController subclass):

```
if let moreList = moreNavigationController.viewControllers.first(where: { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UIMoreListController" }) {
  moreList.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

Answer (score 1):

Just go with the `leftBarButtonItem`

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

OR

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

Comment: not hiding the back button text . Please refer my question